# Why does this USB Keyboard disconnect?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I usually use a PS/2 keyboard however after buying a USB keyboard I am able to use it. It works correctly in bios, as well as on my windows computer, so I believe it is not a problem with the hardware.

`lsusb` does not show the device

`dmesg` says the device has been disconnected, however it is physically connected.

```
[  267.428057] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  267.555545] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1017, idProduct=2010
[  267.555550] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  267.555552] usb 2-1.2: Product: Gaming Keyboard
[  267.569972] input: Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1017:2010.0006/input/input19
[  267.624549] hid-generic 0003:1017:2010.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  268.235649] input: Gaming Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/0003:1017:2010.0007/input/input20
[  268.288697] hid-generic 0003:1017:2010.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Gaming Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1
[  268.288980] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

Any suggestion for identifying the cause of this?

Comment: Is this a funky non-standard gaming keyboard? If not: what's the make and model?

Comment: As far as I can tell it has no special features. It's a "Thinkway Tiny Mech" keyboard, since it works correctly in bios I do not think it is a driver issue.

Comment: it seems to identify itself as a gaming keyboard; it may be doing something similar to what's described in the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401722/222377 ... that issue is specific to FreeBSD, but describes how *"works correctly in bios"* might coexist with *"driver issue"*.